# Website worked yesterday, but not today

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, wordpress

I was working with my website yesterday when I was at home using my web address. Everything seemed fine. When I got to work today, I tried opening my website, and now the connection times out. I can still access my Virtualmin interface, just not the actual website. What could cause this, as I had made no changes to Virtualmin since it was working yesterday.

Note: I have also restarted my server to try and resolve the issue.

Site: www.weekshouse.com
Server: Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)
CMS: Wordpress

Comment: This site is for professionals, and we expect questions to reflect real issues you're experiencing in a professional environment. Being that this is a personal website, being served from your house, it's off-topic.

Comment: In addition, you really haven't provided enough information about your environment to enable anyone to give you a good answer. Are you sure that your webserver is running?

Comment: Okay, thank you ErikA. Were might I ask this question to get support then?

Comment: What additional info is needed? And yes apache is running.

Comment: First, before asking anyone else, read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Then once you've read and internalized that, perhaps go over to our sister site [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) and ask there.

Comment: Thanks ErikA. I appreciate your criticism and demoralizing support. When someone comes here for support, they expect someone to HELP them find their way and to provide solutions. Not tell them all the reasons that their question isn't good enough.

Comment: I'm honestly sorry you feel demoralized. We do expect users to read our FAQ, though, and adhere to it. Any questions not in keeping with the FAQ get closed or migrated. I intended no offense, but rather was trying to guide you on how you'd be able to get better help in the future. Answer quality is in direct proportion to the quality of the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Port 80 is not open on your server (or nothing is listening there):

```
$ nmap www.weekshouse.com

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-05-09 11:49 CDT
Nmap scan report for www.weekshouse.com (174.61.209.88)
Host is up (0.086s latency).
rDNS record for 174.61.209.88: c-174-61-209-88.hsd1.wa.comcast.net
Not shown: 989 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp    closed ftp-data
21/tcp    open   ftp
22/tcp    open   ssh
23/tcp    closed telnet
25/tcp    open   smtp
53/tcp    closed domain
119/tcp   closed nntp
443/tcp   closed https
3389/tcp  open   ms-term-serv
8080/tcp  open   http-proxy
10000/tcp open   snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.36 seconds
```

Comment: I am new to home serving. Any idea how I can fix this.

Comment: Note: I have had it working just before installing wordpress.

Comment: It was probably working because you were INSIDE your home network and weren't going through a firewall to get to it.